# Is it possible to serve Complex GML Features with Mapserver?

Tags: wfs, mapserver, inspire

I want to serve complex GML-Features through WFS 2.0.0 with MapServer. While support for WFS 2.0 was added to Mapserver, I cannot find any current information whether it is possible to serve complex features in Mapserver. Mapserver-Documentation under http://mapserver.org/ogc/inspire_dl.html only talks about metadata.

I know other map servers can handle Complex Features (e.g. GeoServer through its appschema-extension), but is it currently possible in Mapserver (or will it be in the near future)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple answer here is **no** MapServer cannot though it's standard interface provide a Complex Feature WFS.  You might though be able to write some MapScript to create such output.